# Splitting a string with a Regex results in wrong output

Tags: c#, regex

So I have this string which I want to serialize as a GS1 Data Matrix:

```
var code = (01)09501101020917(17)190508(10)ABCD1234(410)9501101020917
```

According to the [Guidelines](https://www.gs1.org/docs/barcodes/GS1_DataMatrix_Guideline.pdf) this isn't valid, because the Application Identifier (10) has a variable length so I need a  (ascii code 29) separator at the end of that section (so something like this
`"(10)ABCD1234{(char) 29}"`

So I split my input string into parts, one part the Application Identifier (AI) and the other part being the data.

My Regex and code for getting the AIs:

```
var identifierRegex = new Regex(@"\([0-9]{2,}\)", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
var identifiers = identifierRegex.Split(code);
```

This returns me almost the correct result, `identifiers` is a `string[]` containing 5 elements, the first one being empty and the rest are correct.

My Regex and code for getting the AIs and the data:

```
var dataRegex = new Regex(@"\([0-9]{2,}\)[0-9A-z]{0,}", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
var aisAndData = dataRegex.Split(code);
```

This returns me the completely wrong results, `aisAndData` is a `string[]` with 5 empty elements

[Here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%28%5b0-9%5d%7b2%2c%7d%5c%29&i=%2801%2909501101020917%2817%29190508%2810%29ABCD1234%28410%299501101020917) is a link to regexstorm.net showing the expected results of the first Regex. And [Here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%28%5b0-9%5d%7b2%2c%7d%5c%29%5b0-9A-z%5d%7b0%2c%7d&i=%2801%2909501101020917%2817%29190508%2810%29ABCD1234%28410%299501101020917) is a link to regexstorm.net showing the expected result of the second Regex

What am I missing/ what am I doing wrong for my code not to work?

Comment: If you have *matching* patterns, why use `Regex.Split`? Use `Regex.Matches`. Note `A-z` must be `A-Za-z`. `var identifiers = identifierRegex.Matches(code).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value)`.

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding you @WiktorStribiżew as I'm pretty new to Regex. I'm trying to get all the parts of my original string (`code`) that match my Regex, for example I want to get `{(01), (17), (10), (410)}` from my identifier Regex

Comment: Exactly, why use `Split` if you need to match?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What else should I use? The Regex.Split documentation makes it pretty clear this is what I want to use stating that the Regex.Split Method "Splits an input string into an array of substrings at the positions defined by a regular expression match"

Comment: Because `splitting` means *removing text you match with the regex pattern and returning only the text that was not matched*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, I see I misunderstood the documentation and the multiple SO questions about it